# What is an "ed school"?

Tags: meaning

On page 82 of Elizabeth Green's *Building a Better Teacher*, the second and third paragraph mentions "ed school" a couple of times, what does it mean? Here's the original text--

> An Oxford professor named Harry Judge, touring American ed schools at
>   the request of the Ford Foundation, described the university approach
>   as “the doctrine of Anything-But.” That is, ed schools were “anything
>   but schools of pedagogy,” an ed school professor told Judge.
>
> The doctrine of Anything-But began with professors. In his final
>   report, Judge described how faculty recruitment happened at a
>   fictional university he named Waterend—a composite representing the
>   elite ed schools he’d toured:

Comment: Teacher college. Ed = education.

Answer (score 4):

An "**Ed School**" is a department within a university or a stand-alone college that focuses on preparing teachers for their profession; also known as "**Normal School,**" "**Teacher's College**" or "**Teacher-Training College**." http://www.memidex.com/normal-school